# Error: System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: apex, lightning, rest-api, controller, json

I have a requirement where the data from external system is fetched and upserted back in Salesforce.

below is my apex class:

```
public class RESTClass {
    @future(callout=true)
    
    public static void RESTClass() {   
        
        String jsonbody = '{ ' +
            '"username": "<username>",' +
            '"password": "<password>"' +
            '}' ;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        req.setEndpoint('<user auth endpoint>');
        req.setBody(jsonBody);   
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        String response = res.getBody();
        UserAuthJSONParser jsondes = (UserAuthJSONParser) JSON.deserialize(response, UserAuthJSONParser.class);
        HttpRequest policyreq = new HttpRequest();
        policyreq.setMethod('GET');
        policyreq.setTimeout(120000);
        policyreq.setEndpoint('<main endpoint>'); 
        policyreq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jsondes.value.token);
        Http policyhttp = new Http();
        HTTPResponse policyres = policyhttp.send(policyreq);
        String policyresponse = policyres.getBody();
        
        JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(policyresponse, JsonParser.class);
        
        JsonParser.cls_value clsValue = objJsonParser.value;
        Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data> clsDataMap = new Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data>();
        
      
        for(JsonParser.cls_data objClsData: clsValue.data){
            clsDataMap.put(objClsData.id, objClsData);
        }
        list<policy__c> updatelist = new list<policy__c>();
        
      
        for (String eachIdFromMap : clsDataMap.keySet()){
            
            policy__c policy = new policy__c(
                unique_id__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).id,
                agent_id__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).agentId);
            updatelist.add(policy);  
        }
        upsert updatelist unique_id__c;
    }    
    
}
```

When I run the above class, I can able to see the output but on few occassions, I am getting following error

> System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Can anyone please let me know if I am missing anything from my class which is causing this error.

Thanks!

Comment: if at all possible, `Json.deserialize` into an ApexType rather than use JsonParser and this will avoid these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `policyresponse` you might be getting an empty string `''` or a whitespace string `' '`.

You can do a anonymous apex and check with this code:

`JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize('', JsonParser.class);`

OR

`JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(' ', JsonParser.class);`

Do proper String null, empty and Blank check before `deserialize` method.
[String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class in Apex has a `isNotBlank` method which checks for all three. You can use it then do your `deserialize` logic.

`if(String.isNotBlank(policyresponse))`

Comment: thanks for the solution!